# How do I implement marshalling in a VC++ ATL COM server?

Tags: windows, com, marshalling, com-interop, atl

While implementing my own IFilter I found that most likely some consumers will require marshalling from it. That is they QueryInterface() the `IMarshal` interface from my object.

Proxy/stubs from MIDL can't be used - MIDL will not compile the `filter.idl` file - the latter uses custom structures and MIDL doesn't know what to do with them. So it looks like I need to implement marshalling on my own.

Where can I find a guide and samples of how to implement marshaling?

Comment: The IDL language does have facilities to describe custom structures so they can be marshalled.  Before you go off implementing your our marshalling you should verify you cannot describe these custom structures in the IDL.

Comment: I looked into it carefully. Turns out, the problem is OLE marshaller that implements the typelib marshalling can't work with structures. So I'll at least need proxy/stub marshalling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this CodeProject article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/CustomMarshaling01.aspx